# C++ calling base class unexpectedly?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got the following code snippet:

```
class Base{
 public:
  virtual float operator()(float x){return x;};
};

class Child: public Base{
 public:
  virtual float operator()(float x) override{return 2 * x;};
};

void scoped(Base b){
    std::cout << "Nested: " << b(5) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Child c = Child();
    std::cout << "Output: " << c(10) << std::endl ;
    scoped(c);
}
```

The output

```
20  // expected
5  // unexpected. Should ahve been doubled?
```

**context**

I'm making `scoped` take a base class because I've got multiple child classes derived from it. On one hand I suppose it makes sense that it would called the `()` from the base class since that's what the type is declared as. On the other hand, why wouldn't it call the method from the instance (which is a `Child` first, then a `Base`?)

**Questions**

1. Am I missing something? How would I accomplish what I'm aiming to do? I get the feeling that templates *may* be a solution but maybe are not the right one?
2. Why is it calling the base class method as opposed to the child

Comment: To avoid the object-slicing, change your function to `void scoped(Base & b)` instead.  Passing-by-reference avoids the need to copy the object, which avoids the slicing that occurs when copying a `Child` into a `Base`

Comment: With `scoped(Base b)`, when you call `scoped(c)`, you create a new (temporary) `Base` object and pass it to function `scoped`. Changing `Base` to `Base&` would tell the compiler that instead of creating that temporary object, it should just pass a reference to the `c` object, whose type is of course `Child`. Of course, the compiler doesn't actually do all of this "runtime stuff" that I just described. But it does generate code which will do exactly that during runtime.

Comment: The parameter to `scoped` is a `Base`. There is no way to pass it an instance of any other class. Also, the code is not `const`-correct, which makes things harder all around.

Comment: Let me guess, you know Java and are trying to learn C++? This is how objects work in Java, but not in C++.

Comment: Python, actually. And thanks everyone! I've sorted my code and read through the answer of the other question